# Group values with same ID

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to concatenate some values with same ID:

```
ID     Value1     Value2     Value3

1      Red     
2      Black
3      Blue
1                 High
2                 Tall
4                            left
```

My final table should be:

```
ID    Value1     Value2     Value3

1     Red        High
2     Black      Tall
3     Blue
4                           left
```

I tried the piece of code below, it work with a simple exemple but not with my data:

```
Sub Concatene()
Dim I As Integer, Txt As String
Dim e As Integer, y As Integer
Sheets("ARTICLE").Select
For I = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
    Txt = LCase(Cells(I, 1).Value)
    If Txt <> "" Then
        'Compare other rows
        For e = I - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If LCase(Cells(e, 1)) = Txt Then
            'There is a duplicate
                For y = 2 To Cells(I, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
                    'concatenate 
                    If Cells(I, y) <> "" And Cells(e, y) = "" Then
                        Cells(e, y) = Cells(I, y)
                    End If
                Next y
                'Delete row
                Rows(I).Delete
            End If
        Next e
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Some help would be great.

Thank in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work no matter the size of the list as long as there are no empty rows.  It is also much faster than deleting the rows.

```
Sub CondenseList()
    Dim Data, NewData
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim index As Long, x As Long, y As Long

    Data = Sheets("ARTICLE").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Value
    ReDim NewData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To UBound(Data, 2))
    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Not list.Contains(Data(x, 1)) Then list.Add Data(x, 1)

        index = list.LastIndexOf(Data(x, 1)) + 1

        For y = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            If Data(x, y) <> vbNullString Then NewData(index, y) = Data(x, y)
        Next
    Next

    Sheets("ARTICLE").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Value = NewData

End Sub
```

### Update: Code breakdown

- All the values from the Target range are loaded into the Data array
- The NewData array is sized to match the Data array
- Next unique ID's are added to an ArrayList
- The position off the unique ID's in the ArrayList determines the index that values for that unique ID are written to in the NewData array
- Final the NewData array overwrites the values in Target range

[image]

Comment: thanks, it seems to work, at least there are no duplicate left. I'll verify the result and I accept your answer :)

Comment: By the way, can you explain a bit your code, I don't understand it at all ^^'

Comment: I added a brief description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Concatene()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim row2 As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim used As Long
    Dim col As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To lastrow
        For row2 = 2 To lastrow
            If Cells(row, 1) = Cells(row2, 1) And row <> row2 Then
                For col = 2 To 4 'Columns with value. Your example said from column 2 to 4.
                    If Cells(row, col) = "" Then 'Will only write if its empty
                        Cells(row, col) = Cells(row2, col)
                        used = 1 'Line is used...
                    End If
                Next col
                If used = 1 Then '...So it can be deleted
                    used = 0
                    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
                    Rows(row2).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next row2
    Next row
End sub
```

Comment: thank you for your time, it works with a simple exemple, i'll run it with my real data and I tell you if it works =)

Comment: it works for some values but not all, some ID are still on many rows